# how to convert this to htmlcharacters: “ and ”

Tags: php, encoding, special-characters

We have these characters:

`“` and `”`

(this is not a regular `"`, but some sort of curly one. No idea what it is called)

When we use `htmlentities()`, these characters are not converted, and this causes issues later on. Further problem is that we encode our pages in `Latin-1`, and we can not save this particular character (so we can not do a replace-and-find, because we can not actually program this into any page).

NOTE: We DO set `ENT_QUOTES`, but this has no effect in `htmlentities()`.

**UPDATE**

I now know they are called fancy quotes, among others, and their appropriate html entities are `&#8220;` and `&#8221;`. Now, the question is, why does PHP *not* convert these characters appropriately? See sample code:

```
<?php
var_dump(htmlentities($_POST['t'],ENT_QUOTES));
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="t" name="t" />
<button class="button" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: They're "smart quotes". Unicode U+201C and U+201D. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs

Comment: Strictly speaking, "smart quotes" just refers to the functionality in e.g. MS Word which automatically converts straight quotation marks into quotation marks.

Comment: @user852091: [`ENT_QUOTES` only affects straight quotation marks.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal Copy that, but how do we convert these characters then?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: that _could_ work but I code in Latin-1 and this character is not allowed; I can not actually save this in my PHP file...

Comment: @user852091: http://shiflett.org/blog/2005/oct/convert-smart-quotes-with-php

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Excellent, that will work! If you could post this as an answer I can mark it as solved!

Comment: First step, get rid of your Latin-1 encoding, it’s pure garbage. Use a proper, modern encoding like UTF-8.

Comment: @Konrad: thanks for the tip but this is not really constructive. I am bound due to restrictions to use Latin-1. My question is how to get the html entities, given this encoding. Thanks.

Comment: @user852091 I would question those restrictions. You are clearly getting non-Latin-1 characters as input. The next question would be what encoding the input is using. Before we know this we can’t say why the replace calls fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer comes from http://shiflett.org/blog/2005/oct/convert-smart-quotes-with-php, which was posted as a comment by Tomalak Geret'kal:

The trick is to use the `ascii` character position to find the characters that we are targeting, and then convert them with the ones we can work with. Eg:

```
<?php
function convert_smart_quotes($string) 
{ 
    $search = array(chr(145), 
                    chr(146), 
                    chr(147), 
                    chr(148), 
                    chr(151)); 

    $replace = array("'", 
                     "'", 
                     '"', 
                     '"', 
                     '-'); 

    return str_replace($search, $replace, $string); 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `htmlentities()`  It covers all characters that have an html entity equivalent.

[htmlentities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

**UPDATE**

You need to alter the charset.

`echo htmlentities("“jrod”", ENT_QUOTES, "Windows-1252");`

**Update 2**

```
<?php
var_dump(htmlentities($_POST['t'],ENT_QUOTES, "Windows-1252"));
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="t" name="t" />
<button class="button" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

String used: `“testing”`

Var dump output: `string(21) "&ldquo;testing&rdquo;"`

Mind you, to see the html equivalents you have to view source as the browser renders them accordingly.

Comment: Should produce a left and right double quote with `&ldquo;` and `&rdquo;` respectively

Comment: Sorry, that is what we use indeed, I mixed it up but updated the post to reflect this.

Comment: By setting the charset parameter you can get the expected results.

Comment: Do you get the html equivalents? Try with the script I posted before, using POST as input and ISO-8859-1 as encoding. Here I can not get it to work...

Comment: I modified your script and posted the update. The "Windows-1252" encoding was the first charset I tried that produced the proper html entities.

Comment: I am using ISO-8859-1 so I prefer not to use another charset for this conversion; I'd like to solve this by using this same charset.

Comment: Left and right double quotes don't exist in that charset.

I suggest reading this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs#Quotation_marks_in_electronic_documents

Answer (score 1):

There called “fancy quotes,” “smart quotes,” “curly quotes,” “curled quotes,” “curling quotes,” or “curved quotes”

```
Left Double Quotation Mark  &#8220; “
Right Double Quotation Mark &#8221; ”
```

You may find this link helpfull: http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/quotes-in-html.html